# In the package `glm`, it is possible to change the default likelihood functions for the distributions?

Tags: r

I am currently trying to create my custom likelihood function for a logistic model in the `glm` package. The most standard approach is to use `optim`, `mle2`, etc. However, these are often slow and clunky. Would it be possible to go into the functions of the `glm` package and hardcode my custom likelihood function? Would there be any problems with this? Does this have anything to do with the **link** specification in `glm`? Thank you!

Comment: `glm` is a function in the stats package, not a pack unto itself. You can specify custom `family` objects for estimating different kinds of models but presumably if you already have your likelihood function you could just build something around `optim`, unless I misunderstand your question.

Comment: I have not seen anyone modifying the `glm` function for this purpose. The approach I'm accustomed to is writing the log likelihood and pushing it to `optim`, `nls` and kin... Why would you consider this approach 'clunky'? I think flexible would be a better term.